# How can I remove leading two integers with python script?

Tags: python, regex

I have a txt file containing many rows with coordinates in the following format:

```
0;32520010,00;5840530,00;1;22,45;0,16;0,01;0,16;295,46;
```

I need to remove the leading "32" from all of the first coordinates - ie making 32520010,00; into 520010,00; and write the line into a new file whilst keeping all other characters.
I have been trying with the following python script but the problem arises when the coordinate becomes longer than 10 characters.

```
for line in readf:
    p = re.compile(r"32(520000,00;)")        
    result =  p.sub('\g<1>',line)
```

How could I adapt this to become a bit more flexible and account for the fact the coordinate could be longer or shorter than 10 characters?

Comment: what do you want to do with numbers that are 2 characters or less? How do you want your output? do you only want to remove it if it starts with "32"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the `re` module, the following works:

```
import re

line = "0;32520010,00;5840530,00;1;22,45;0,16;0,01;0,16;295,46;"

m = re.match(r"^(\d+;)32(.+)", line)
result =  m.group(1) + m.group(2)
print(result)
```

The regular expression matches the first number up to the semicolon, then the 32, then the rest. Everything except the 32 is captured in groups and then merged together.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a problem you need `regex` for:

```
>>> line = "0;32520010,00;5840530,00;1;22,45;0,16;0,01;0,16;295,46;"
>>> subs = line.split(";")
>>> subs[1] = subs[1][2:]
>>> subs
['0', '520010,00', '5840530,00', '1', '22,45', '0,16', '0,01', '0,16', '295,46', '']
>>> ";".join(subs)
'0;520010,00;5840530,00;1;22,45;0,16;0,01;0,16;295,46;'
```

This approach will indiscriminately lop off the two first characters of whatever is between the first and second `;`.  It doesn't care what those characters are, and it doesn't care how long the string is (strings shorter than 2 will result in `''`).

Answer (score 2):

```
line = "0;32520010,00;5840530,00;1;22,45;0,16;0,01;0,16;295,46;"

p = re.compile(r"32(\d+,\d+;)")        
result =  p.sub('\g<1>',line)
print(result)
```

Using the `\d+` will give you one or more digits. This should be what you're looking for.

It'll replace all instances where the first coordinate starts with `32` and remove it.

Comment: But this does require that you know what the first two characters are before they are removed, yes?

Comment: Doesn't this work on all coordinates that start with 32?

Comment: @wnnmaw:  `p = re.compile(re.escape(arbitrary_string) + r"(\d+,\d+;)")`

Comment: In this case, yes but you could easily make it more flexible for instances where you don't know the number until runtime. However, the question states it'll always be 32.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a look ahead assertion in `re.sub`

```
>>> import re
>>> x="0;32520010,00;5840530,00;1;22,45;0,16;0,01;0,16;295,46;"
>>> re.sub(r'32(?=520010)','',x)
'0;520010,00;5840530,00;1;22,45;0,16;0,01;0,16;295,46;'
```

The regex `32(?=520010)` would match any `32` which is followed by a `520010`

If you are uncertain about what may follow the `32` a look behind would be usefull

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\d;)32','',x)
'0;520010,00;5840530,00;1;22,45;0,16;0,01;0,16;295,46;'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative way,

```
>>> s = '0;32520010,00;5840530,00;1;22,45;0,16;0,01;0,16;295,46;'
>>> ';'.join(map((lambda x: x.replace('32','') if x.startswith('32') else x ), s.split(';')))
'0;520010,00;5840530,00;1;22,45;0,16;0,01;0,16;295,46;'
```